# How to solve Pygame program continuously eats up memory when running?

Tags: python, memory-leaks

I am creating a simple program that has a background image, raining visuals, and sound effects. I used Sprite classes to create raindrops and rain splashes. When I run the program, I observed from the activity monitor that Python occupied around 90MB of memory at first, then increased to more than 500MB when I leave the program window open for a few more minutes.

I thought it was due to not deleting the out-of-screen sprites (rain and rain splashes) correctly. So I used the print method to check the length of their corresponding group but saw everything was fine, the amount of sprites was not piling up. After some examination, I found the problem very likely lies in the function delete_dissapeared_raindrops(). However, I am not able to come up with a reasonable explanation for myself.

I have tried my best to follow the rules but I have very little experience in using StackOverflow so please forgive me for my unprofessional. Here is the code that presents the same issue. You will need a picture loaded to Raindrop class and observe the memory consumption in the OS.

```
import sys
from random import randint

import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Group
from pygame.sprite import Sprite


# class
class Raindrop(Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        """initiate raindrop"""

        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load('image/raindrop.bmp').convert_alpha()
        
        y_pos = randint(-screen_height, 0)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(centery = y_pos)

    def update(self):
        """let the raindrop drops from top to bottom"""
        self.rect.y += 8

    def check_edge(self):
        """check if raindrop reaches the bottom of the screen"""
        if self.rect.top >= screen_height:
            return True


# functions
def update_screen():
    screen.fill('black')
    rain.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()


# functions
def get_available_raindrops_x(raindrop_width):
    """calculate how many raindrops available horizontally"""
    available_space = screen_width - (2 * raindrop_width)
    available_raindrops = int(available_space / 
        (2 * raindrop_width))
    return available_raindrops


def create_rain():
    if len(rain) <= 58:
        raindrop = Raindrop()
        available_raindrops = get_available_raindrops_x(raindrop.rect.width)
        for i in range(available_raindrops):
            raindrop = Raindrop()
            # raindrops are placed away from each other horizontally
            raindrop.rect.x += raindrop.rect.width + (raindrop.rect.width * 2) * i
            rain.add(raindrop)


def delete_dissapeared_raindrops():
    """delete the raindrops that crossed the bottom of the screen"""
    for raindrop in rain.copy():
        if raindrop.check_edge():
            rain.remove(raindrop)


def update_screen():
    screen.fill('black')
    rain.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()


# settings
screen_width = 1200
screen_height = 820

# initialization
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 120
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

# initializing sprite group
rain = Group()


# main program loop
while True:

    clock.tick(fps)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    # creating and deleting rain
    print(len(rain))
    create_rain()
    rain.update()
    delete_dissapeared_raindrops()

    update_screen()
```

Comment: I'm familiar with Python, but not PyGame, so I'm sorry if this isn't helpful, but generally speaking this is a job for a "profiler". It looks like PyGame has some info: https://www.pygame.org/wiki/Profiling

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually removing the raindrop from the group, you can use the built-in kill() method of the Sprite class. This will remove the sprite from all groups it belongs to.

In your create_rain() function, you're calling get_available_raindrops_x(raindrop.rect.width) inside a loop, which is unnecessary since the screen width and the raindrop width are constant. Call this function once and store the value.

Comment: Yes, using kill() method solves the issue, but I do not understand why deleting the raindrops using delete_dissapeared_raindrops() function does not work. Do you have any idea why? You're right, calling the function once and storing the value is a better choice.